# Did someone give a formal definition of normal and applicative order?

Tags: lo.logic, pl.programming-languages, lambda-calculus

In all courses and textbooks I have seen, normal order reduction (NOR) and applicative order reduction (AOR) are defined as reducing respectively the leftmost outermost and rightmost innermost redex. Did someone ever give a more formal definition? (in some texts, I saw call-by-value and call-by-name formally defined, but IIUC, they are not exactly NOR and AOR, just in the same families of evaluation stratetgies)

Would the following definition of NOR be correct:

```
NOR(x) = ∅
NOR(λx.B) = NOR(B)
NOR(M N) =
  if ∃ x,B | M = λx.B
  then (M N)
  else
    if NOR(M) ≠ ∅
    then NOR(M)
    else NOR(N)
```

Comment: You are asking us how to translate a perfectly understandable informal explanation to something involving symbolic notation. This is an exercise, not a research level question. I would suggest that you ask your question on http://stackoverflow.com/, and ask "where can I see an implementation of the normal order evaluation strategy, or at the very least written down formally?"

Comment: Since when is defining something formally not a "research level" matter? Any decent scientific article that proves anything either builds on formal definitions by someone else or begins with formal definitions…

Comment: In the present case the formal definition is not very challenging.

Comment: I never thought it to be challenging, I'm just wondering if there may be a subtle difference between my understanding of a perfectly understandable informal explanation and an hypothetically canonical formal definition. But let's face it, there's never a difference between the interpretation of something informal and its formal counterpart…

Comment: Well, for what is worth, I don't quite understand what your definition is supposed to accomplish. Normal-form evaluation should be some sort of a transition system, and you seem to be defining a function which takes a term and returns either the empty set or a term. That's a bit strange. Are you using the empty set as "no answer"?

Comment: As I describe it, the function returns the redex that the reduction order "selects" and, yes, the empty set would then mean "nothing".

Comment: I answered this question because I considered it as some kind of request for references which I managed to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formal definitions of the applicative order reduction and the normal order reduction are given, in particular, in the monograph by Barendregt (The Lambda Calculus: Its Syntax and Semantics).

Specifically, the normal strategy is described as that choosing the leftmost redex. The leftmost redex is in turn described as such a $\beta$-redex $(\lambda x.M)\; N$ whose $\lambda$ symbol is on the left of any other redex' $\lambda$ symbol. For instance, in the following expression the normal strategy is to choose the whole expression for $\beta$-reduction:

$$
(\lambda x.(\lambda y.x)\; z)\; (\lambda x.x).
$$

When lambda expressions are represented using graphs, the same strategy is sometimes called leftmost-outermost strategy.